# Can I use index alias on "indexName" used for @Document annotation?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

On a project we use elasticsearch and from time to time we need to change indexes during switchovers. We would like this to have minimal impact on Java code that uses this index.

Currently we have this kind of code:

```
@Document(indexName="someIndex", ...)
public class SomeClass
```

My questions are:

- IndexName can refer to an alias ? (aliases which will be managed via the REST API or the Java API/IndicesAliasesRequest)
- If not, can we manage it differently via Java code? Maybe by not going through @Document annotation.

At the moment I am very limited in testing, I hope for minimal impact on existing code.

Answer (score 0):

The indexName field can actually be an alias. It works !